# Should we replace tag "expression" with "ssrs-expression"?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Today I saw [a person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156018/curiousguy?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) who's replacing [expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression) with [ssrs-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssrs-expression). For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10626737), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10626734), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10626677) suggested edit.

I've notice that [expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression) is older than [ssrs-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssrs-expression). The first one has 4,146 questions at this moment, but the second one only has 95.

So, is replacing tag [expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression) with [ssrs-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssrs-expression) correct?

Comment: User has suggested over 30 tag edits in past couple of days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two very different tags. [expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression) is about:

> An expression is code before it gets evaluated. That is, evaluating an expression will give you a result.

While [ssrs-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssrs-expression) is quite specific to SSRS:

> To set expression in SSRS Report. SSRS-Expressions are frequently used in SSRS Reports to control content and report appearance.

So each instance should be evaluated separately. IMHO, it's an appropriate edit for the first two examples you presented, but not for the third (frankly, I'd just remove the expression tag there altogether). Note that many questions tagged with [expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression) don't have anything to do with SSRS - there are [java questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression%20java?mode=all) there, [C questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression%20c?mode=all), [python questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression%20python?mode=all), you name it.

Comment: Huh, seems so. Then we should check these edits manually, and approve correct ones, reject incorrect ones right? Do we need tell this user about it?

Comment: @KevinGuan most of his edits seem to be focused on questions that are indeed about SRSS. At least from a brief look, most seem to be valid edits, and for the cases that aren't - that's what rejects were invented for. If you think he's blindly editing just leave him a comment.

Comment: Okay, that's fine :)